# How do I configure the hbm2java maven2 plugin to generate POJOs for all mapping files

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, hbm2java

I am trying to migrate my ant build to maven2. in my build.xml I invoke the hbm2java in the following way:

```
<hibernatetool destdir="/src/generated/">
        <configuration configurationfile="${env.ITP_HOME}/core/xml/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml">
            <fileset dir="/xml/hibernate">
                <include name="*.hbm.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
        <hbm2java/>
    </hibernatetool>
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>        
</session-factory>
```

in my maven2 POM file I have:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <id>hbm2java</id>
  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>hbm2java</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
   <components>
    <component>
     <name>hbm2java</name>
     <implementation>configuration</implementation>
     <outputDirectory>/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
    </component>
   </components>
   <componentProperties>
    <jdk5>true</jdk5>
    <configurationfile>/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
   </componentProperties>
  </configuration>      
 </execution>
```

but when executing `mvn hibernate3:hbm2java` i see no files get generated unless they are all listed in hibernate.cfg.xml.
Is there a way to specify a fileset in the maven configuration similar to the ant task?

thanks,
naor

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I am having the same problem. I do not have a running database and cannot use hbm2cfgxml.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the only way but I would use `hbm2cfgxml` first to generate a `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration file including the `<mapping resource="..."/>` entries and then the `hbm2java` goal to generate the POJOs. Below, a configuration doing this as part of your build:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-xml-files</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-entities</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <components>
      <component>
        <name>hbm2cfgxml</name>
        <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
      </component>
      <component>
        <name>hbm2java</name>
        <implementation>configuration</implementation>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/hibernate3</outputDirectory>
      </component>
    </components>
    <componentProperties>
      <propertyfile>src/main/resources/database.properties</propertyfile>
      <jdk5>true</jdk5>
      <ejb3>false</ejb3>
      <packagename>com.mycompany.myapp</packagename>
      <format>true</format>
      <haltonerror>true</haltonerror>
    </componentProperties>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- your JDBC driver -->
    ...
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Where the `src/main/database.properties` file contains the following information

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=...
hibernate.connection.username=...
hibernate.connection.password=...
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

This setup assumes your `.hbm.xml` are placed in `src/main/resources` (and will thus be copied into `target/classes` for the processing by `hbm2java`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pascal.
I forgot to mention that my ant builds also generates my ddl script to build the database as part of the build (different target). I wish to do a similar thing in my maven2 build using hbm2ddl.
Does your solution requires me to have my database already built to generate the cfg.xml? if so, is there a way to achieve this without pointing to an existing schema?

Comment: @naor I am not sure it does (the database connection info will be used to create the hibernate.cfg.xml), and I can't test this right now. But maybe you can experiment it.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.
I did a local test. unfortunately I do see that the generated hibernate.cfg.xml lists mapping based on the schema I point to.
So far I couldn't find any indication that the maven plugin can supports pointing to a directory where the mapping files are.
my next step would be listing the mapping files manually :-(